# How to find multiple strings in files?

Tags: find, grep

I use the following command to find files with a given string:

```
find /var/www/http -type f | xargs grep -iR "STRING1"
```

But how can I find files which include "STRING1" OR "STRING2" OR "STRING3"?

This code doesn't work:

```
find /var/www/http -type f | xargs grep -iR "STRING1" | xargs grep -iR "STRING2"
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

POSIXly, using `grep` with `-E` option:

```
find /var/www/http -type f -exec grep -iE 'STRING1|STRING2' /dev/null {} +
```

Or `-e`:

```
find /var/www/http -type f -exec grep -i -e 'STRING' -e 'STRING2' /dev/null {} +
```

With some implementations, at least on GNU systems, OSX and FreeBSD, you can escape `|`:

```
find /var/www/http -type f -exec grep -i 'STRING1\|STRING2' /dev/null {} +
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I edited with the portable one first, would you mind removing the comment so readers won't be confused.

Answer (score 8):

For ease of maintenance (if your list of strings to search may change in the future), I would put the patterns in a file (eg. patterns.txt) and use the `-f` switch (`-R` is unnecessary if you are restricting `find` to files; `-H` will give you the file name in case there is only one; `-F` causes grep to treat the patterns you are searching for as strings, and not regular expressions, which is usually what you want):

```
find /var/www/http -type f -exec grep -iHFf patterns.txt {} +
```

Comment: just complementing, the strings in the text file patter will be separated by the newline chracter

Answer (score 7):

What's wrong with just using `egrep`?

```
egrep -r 'string1|string2|string3' /var/www/http
```

Comment: You should use `grep -E ...`. According to the `(e)grep` man page direct invocation of `egrep` is deprecated and the command is only provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.

Comment: Also note that `-r` is not found on every implementations of the (non-standard) `egrep` command.