# How to find file with multiple strings

Tags: grep, find

Suppose I have a file named

> some_file_name.ext

Now I want this file to be found out with find command some part of filename like:

```
find filelocation -type f -name 'some\|name'
```

I have tried doing this with grep and awk but with no luck and even tried all command from [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85808/how-to-find-multiple-strings-in-files)

Comment: Do you want to match files whose names match both `some` **and** `name`? is order important?

Comment: Order is not important further I want some&name instead of some|name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to `find -name` are simple shell globs, and the default conjunction is logical `AND` - so

```
find location -type f -name '*some*' -name '*name*'
```

will find regular files whose names contain both `some` and `name` in any order. OTOH if you want to find files whose names contain `some` and `name` in order, it's simply

```
find location -type f -name '*some*name*'
```

or

```
find location -type f -name 'some*name*'
```

if the name should *start with* the string `some`.